# Which mount point to use in dual or triple boot for Grub?

Tags: multi-boot, mount, grub

So i have to choose a mount point for Grub during the last Linux install (Windows was installed first), but does it even matter if it will be dual or triple boot, if Windows 7 basically holds the main boot loader anyway?

And which mount point should i point the Grub to if Windows is probably on /sda1 and Linux /root will be at /sda4?
It is basically only 1 /sda disk, so maybe i should point it to /sda instead, or would /sda4 keep it safe from any possible Windows partition failures if Grub is on /sda4?

Comment: pointing the Grub install on a separate "/" (sda5) or "/boot" (sda4 etc...) partition did not work at all... so maybe just "/sda" will work? would that affect the default Windows "/sda1" bootloader in some ways though?

Comment: NB! now i can confirm that you can make a separate /boot partition and then you must actually just choose the default "/sda" option during the installation and only then it will work and boot up (choosing "/sda5" or something else will probably require to use some 3rd party Mbr editor to add Linux to the boot list..)

Answer (score 0):

When dual booting or triple booting a system, i would suggest creating a **seperate partition for grub** so that if the windows bootloader partition is damaged somehow then you can boot into Linux without any worries.

When you create a seperate partition for grub in Linux installation, the first time you boot into Linux it will update and create a copy of grub bootloader in windows bootloader partition so everytime you boot it will show you two options:

1. Booting in Linux
2. Booting into Windows
   (This will be shown on the grub menu itself)

Try creating the partition size of 1 GB for grub for further future updates.

Thank You!
Hope this gives you an answer.

Comment: ok, but can it be on /sda4 also then or would it also work on a separate 200mb /boot partition? (which would probably be /sda4 again, and /root would be /sda5 then.. and 1gb seems a bit too much for such a small 'text app' to use all of that space?:s).

and what could be the difference between just Grub on /root vs Grub on separate /boot partition... (in a multi-boot system...)

Comment: You cannot install grub on the partition on which you are installing the linux files, grub needs a separate partition on which it installs grub configuration files as well as the kernel files which contains system.map which generally takes around ~250MB to 1GB may differ in size on different linux distros.

Comment: well, i dont even know if it's Grub or what, but it asks for "Device for boot loader installation" and gives options from /sda to /sda7 etc... so which one should i pick from there.

and maybe the /boot partition is only needed in multi--boot systems then?

Comment: When installing Linux we generally create 3 types of partitions i.e. 1.  /root - in which system files are installed, 2. /boot - in which bootloader is installed - example (grub), 3. /swap - swap memory. And no /boot partition is required in every kind of installation whether dual boot or single OS.

Comment: When it prompts you to select the partition for bootloader installation, you should select the partition which is marked as /boot or just remember the size of the partition which you created for bootloader installation then you can easily figure out the partition by comparing the size of each partition and select that one to install.

Comment: well, now i'm just stuck again lol... another system actually says it a bit more straight forward: "Install the Grub boot menu on:" - and then gives options from /sda to /sda7 etc... previously i pointed it to the "/" partition, but that didn't work, so would it work with a separate /boot partition now ("/sda5") or do i still have to leave it as default and point it to "/sda"?

Comment: or maybe i just need to use this repair tool then, because it actually involves both of the locations that are needed?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

Comment: well, now i can confirm that pointing/installing Grub to the separate /boot partition (/sda5) did not work, so i still have to use the default "/sda" option to make it work? maybe it would be the only way for Linux to even know what there is a Windows system installed and then just detects the separate /boot partition also and installs all needed files there too?

Answer (score 0):

Now i can confirm, because i tried all of the options(in multi-boot), that:

whatever it says(for Grub install) or whichever partitions you choose during the (manual) partitioning(/boot or no /boot), just make sure that you select the default "/dev/sda" option at the end and nothing else, because otherwise you have to use some 3rd party boot editor programs to add Linux to the boot list...

(and default /boot partition was used for 104mb, so 250-300mb size should be fine also for it...)